# PostgreSQL how to query jsonb by a value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

I can query to get the following results:

```
{
    "sku0": {
        "Id": "18418",
        "Desc": "yes"
    },
    "sku1": {
        "Id": "17636",
        "Desc": "no"
    },
    "sku2": {
        "Id": "206714",
        "Desc": "yes"
    },
    "brand": "abc",
    "displayName": "something"
}
```

First, the number of skus is not fixed. It may be sku0, sku1, sku2, sku3, sku4 ... but they all start with `sku`.

Then, I want to query Id with **17636** and determine whether its value of **Desc** is yes or no. After reading the [PostgreSQL JSON Functions and Operators documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), Depressing I didn't find a good way.

I can convert the result into a Python dictionary, and then use python's method can easily achieve my requirements.

If the requirements can also be achieved with postgresql statements, which method is more recommended than the Python dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand what the result is you want. But if you want to filter on the Id, you need to unnest all the elements inside the JSON column:

```sql
select d.v ->> 'Desc' as description
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each(t.data) as d(k,v)
where d.v ->> 'Id' = '17636'
```

Comment: Bjarni's answer also solved my question, but I think your answer is more general and transplantable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new jsonpath notation of PostgreSQL v12:

```
SELECT data @@ '$.* ? (@.Id == "17636").Desc == "yes"'
FROM some_table;
```

That will start with the root of `data` (`$`), find any attribute in it (`*`), filter only those attributes that contain an `Id` with value `"17636"`, get their `Desc` attribute and return `TRUE` only if that attribute is `"yes"`.

Nice, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably give you what you need.

```
select value->>'Desc' from jsonb_each('{
    "sku0": {
        "Id": "18418",
        "Desc": "yes"
    },
    "sku1": {
        "Id": "17636",
        "Desc": "no"
    },
    "sku2": {
        "Id": "206714",
        "Desc": "yes"
    },
    "brand": "abc",
    "displayName": "something"
}'::jsonb)
where key like 'sku%'
and value->>'Id'='17636'
```

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Your answer also inspired me, but I think the answer of a_horse_with_no_name is more general and portable